# Upgrading to Mac OS 10.15.7 has erased contacts out of my iCloud conacts book

Tags: icloud, contacts, contacts.app

After upgrading to Mac OS 10.15.7, two contacts who are on my "Favorites" list appear to have their contact records removed from iCloud -- my brother and my doctor office.
The numbers continue to appera in the Favorates list (on my iphone), but since the contact records are gone now show their numbers instead of their names.

I cannot locate the contact records in Contacts (app) on the mac, or in the Contacts app on the phone. I also cannot locate these records in the iCloud.com through access to my icloud account.

they appear to just be vanished completely out of icloud, which is very concerning because I do not know what the scope or impact of this is.

Comment: Have you check 'recently deleted' on iCloud.com?  Anything deleted from iCloud goes into that recycle bin for 30 days, I believe.  Also, is it possible that those contacts were deleted on another device signed-in with the same Apple ID?

Comment: I can't find a recently deleted folder in cloud but I do see that icloud seems to make snapshop backups of the Contacts file that can be restored.

Comment: When in iCloud.com, go to Account Settings.  Scroll down to the bottom of the page and under Advanced you'll see options to recover recently deleted data.